# Execution context of setTimeout (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

1) Can someone illustrate how setTimeout works in terms of execution threads.

Consider:

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); }
function bar() { alert('bar'); }  
setTimeout(foo,1000);
bar();
```

or

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); setTimeout(foo,1000); }
function bar() { alert('bar'); }  
setTimeout(foo,1000);
bar();
```

or

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); setTimeout(foo,1000); }
function bar() { /* an execution that runs with unknown time */ }  
setTimeout(foo,1000);
bar();
```

or

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); setTimeout(foo,1000); }
function bar() { /* some ajax call that reply with unknown time */ }  
setTimeout(foo,1000);
bar();
```

or

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); setTimeout(foo,1000); }
function bar() { alert('foo'); setTimeout(bar,1000); }  
setTimeout(foo,1000);
setTimeout(bar,1000);
```

2) Can someone explain how why "this" object doesn't work in setTimeout and what we can do to get around that problem?

Comment: All of those calls to setTimeout will do nothing at all. You're passing in "foo" as a **string**, which will be interpreted as meaning you want a function whose body looks like the string contents.

Comment: Take a look at the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem

Comment: The context of `setTimeout` is `window`, to use `this` from the function cache it before.

Comment: 1) You are alerted bar, then foo.
2) You are alerted bar, then foo every second. However `setInterval(foo, 100)` would do the same thing better.
3) bar fully executes, and after 10 seconds foo executes. A timer pushes something to the bottom of the priority queue.
4) Again, foo will wait until bar has finished execution.

Answer (score 9):

Do read the article suggested by @DaveAnderson.

As to the other stuff, the setTimeout/setInterval has two forms:

```
setTimeout(arg, timeout)
```

If arg is a string, then it's treated as the source code to be executed. This is as bad as eval(). Avoid it.

If arg is a function, then it's executed in the global context:

```
var Test = function () {
    this.x = 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('x: ' + this.x);
    }, 10);
};

var t = new Test();
```

Prints x: undefined.

So what you wanted to do is:

```
function foo() { alert('foo'); }
setTimeout('foo()', 1000);
```

or better:

```
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

To fix the context of the function, use the bind method:

```
var Test = function () {
    this.x = 1;
    var f = function () {
        console.log('x: ' + this.x);
    };
    setTimeout(f.bind(this), 10);         // use this as the context
};

var t = new Test();
```

or do it manually:

```
var Test = function () {
    this.x = 1;
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('x: ' + that.x);     // closure: closing over that
    }, 10);
};

var t = new Test();
```

Comment: The article I suggested was John Resig's [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) but the answer was deleted by a moderator, hopefully providing this comment is appropriate instead.

Comment: the last approach is quite interesting

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could recall:

```
var me = this;
me.f();
```

(this may change its meaning in another context).

Comment: Conceptually yes, but please fill in the function expression and the call to `setTimeout`.